# Coin cell holder not powering circuit

Tags: power-supply, arduino, load-cell, coin-cell

I use a 3023 Keystone electronics, through-hole coin cell holder in my circuit. When I connect the Arduino to my computer, it gets powered up without any issue and my circuit works just fine.

The **problem** is that when I disconnect it and try to place batteries in my coin cell holder, it does not work, the Arduino's lamp doesn't blink and my circuit doesn't work. The circuit has two load cells, a load cell amplifier, an Arduino, and a coin cell holder.

I don't know if I have to but I thought I heard I had to make different types of wiring on the board for power lines? If not, could it be because I soldered it in the wrong direction?

I tried multiple different batteries but that doesn't seem to be the problem either. I use two 2032 Philips cells in my holder which should give 6 V, the required voltage for the Arduino (33 IoT) to work.

This is the **schematic** of my circuit:

[image: board schematic]

This is the **board**:

[image: board]

This is the **actual board**:

[image: board image]

[image: board image]

[image: board image]

[image: board image]

Comment: Have you measured supply voltage at Arduino power input?

Comment: Do you have a contact plate on the pad marked '3 GND' or is it just the bare pad? What is the expected current draw?

Comment: There is a contact plate on the board, it is not marked 3 GND though. In the datasheet it says the current consumption of the load cell amplifier is for: normal operation < 1.5mA, power down < 1uA.

Comment: @tomcajot Please measure the voltage. Also, you are forgetting that the Arduino and onboard components also draw current.

Comment: Check that the contact pad on the board is making contact with the cell. It may be that the solder mask is higher than the metal and preventing the battery from touching it. Squeeze a small bit of tinfoil or something between the two.

Comment: Can you apply a little bit of solder to the GND pad, and heat it/spread it. It will lift the coin cell up and makes sure the contact is ok. Make a photo of the coincell in situ.

Comment: How is the GND of the pad connected to the GND of the nano? Polygon? Trace? Plane?

Comment: @Justme, RemyHx, I applied a bit of solder to the GND pad. Once I checked the voltage, it was at ~6V but decreased really fast, it was almost halved every second (up to ~0.5V where it started decreasing slower and slower). Something seems to be drawing all the voltage. (I'm reminding that the circuit worked perfectly fine when connected to my computer). Could there be a short between the cell and the Arduino or is something else happening? Also the GND of the pad is connected to the GND of the uno with the top layer being GND everywhere.

Comment: I just changed the cell positions and now it seems to be working, but after some time the bluetooth doesn't work anymore. I have some glue (from tape) on the cells maybe that resists and interferes?

Comment: Check the supply voltage after it's been running for a while. I suspect you're being ambitious trying to power the circuit with two coin cells.

Comment: @Finbarr, I bought two new cells and tried it with them. The Arduino power led shines but the bluetooth is not working. When I check the voltage at VIN I'm at around 4.9V (decreasing slowly), how could I compute how much cells I need?

Comment: That really depends how long you want it to run on batteries before replacing or recharging them. I'd look at a small Lithium pack of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Arduino® Nano 33 IoT [apparently](https://forum.arduino.cc/t/nano-33-iot-vin-voltage-range/599957/20) (the present [official datasheet](https://docs.arduino.cc/static/123868463d7da71f25b468599720c3fb/ABX00027-datasheet.pdf) is not informative) draws current of 40-50mA.

A CR2032 cannot supply that much current, even briefly, and maintain output voltage. A stack of AA batteries would be better, and you'd probably want to activate whatever power-down features it has to minimized current draw when it's not necessary.

One indication that this Arduino is not a particularly low-power device is their choice of a switching supply rather than the linear regulator used in the basic ATmega-based nano.

Comment: What board do you recommend using? I just need to read the data from the load cell amplifier and send it via bluetooth.

Comment: Anything with a transmitter is going to take some juice during the transmit, at least. Some car fobs are powered by a CR2032 however they also have a tiny lithium-ion rechargeable battery to supply the peak current (and the circuitry is designed to draw uA in standby (when a button has not been pushed recently). Depending on how your device is intended to be used, that may not be possible. It's possible if you found a suitable device with BLE a battery or supercapacitor could be used to supply the juice for milliseconds during the transmit.